# Adapted Frenet Frame of Curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, matrix-equations, curves, frenet-frame

Let $\gamma$ be an arclength parameterized Frenet curve. We define the Curvature function to be $$\kappa = \left\lVert\gamma''\right\rVert > 0$$ and the Torsion function to be $$ \tau = \left\langle T \times N,\, N'\right\rangle$$ Show that the adapted frame $F = \left(T, N, T \times N\right): I\to \mathbf{SO}\left(3,R\right)\,$ and calculate $$A = F^{-1}F^{'}$$ in terms of $\kappa$ and $\tau$.

So if anyone could help me with how exactly I show that the adapted frame belongs in the Rotation group that would be exceptional. I know some properties of the rotation group are that the transpose of an element ( a $3\times 3$ matrix) is equivalent to the inverse of that element and also that each element has determinant $1$. But am unsure how to show this with my frame. I imagine I consider the elements $\,\left(T, N, T \times N\right)\,$ to each be $3\times 1$ column vectors and thus I have a $3\times 3$ matrix but beyond that I'm a bit lost.

Also in calculating $A$ I'm a bit unsure how exactly to show that in terms of $\kappa$ and $\tau$, given that $\kappa$ is given in terms of the curve $\gamma$ while $\tau$ is given in terms of the Frenet frame I'm not sure what I should do to move forward. I get that I'll need to take the derivative of $F$ and also take its inverse (really its transpose) then multiply them but then that leaves me with the issue of how exactly to represent the elements of $T, N,$ and $T \times N$. $T$ is easy as $\gamma = \left(x, y, z\right)\,$ so then $T = \gamma' = \left(x', y', z'\right)\,$ but it's not so straightforward depicting the elements for $N$ and $T \times N$. What I tried to do was just choose arbitrary symbols for each vectors elements then remember one set of symbols is orthogonal to another is orthogonal to another but this is quite clumsy and doesn't elucidate much.

Comment: A matrix is orthogonal if and only if its columns form an orthonormal basis. For your question about $A$, write the Frenet equations in matrix form. (See, e.g., p. 11 of my text.)

Comment: Thanks again for the help @TedShifrin. I differentiated F and got a 3x1 matrix with elements, ($\kappa N$), ($-\kappa T$ + $\tau B$) and (-$\tau N$) then I transposed F for the inverse (since F belongs to SO(3,R)) and got a 1x3 row vector of (T, N, B = T x N) and when I multiplied these two matrices I get a scalar since 1x3 * 3x1 = 1x1 and I do, I get zero. I'd just like to make sure that sounds right to you. Getting zero in these sorts of questions seems either to be a godsend or symptomatic of flawed arguments

Comment: Whoa. Slow down. This isn't right. You actually want a $3\times 3$ matrix whose columns are $T,N,B$ for $F$. (Again, look on page 11.)

Comment: Hmm I saw that but was a bit confused on how I should carry out the matrix multiplication with T as a whole column rather than just one element and so I was looking on wikipedia [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas] and saw that they had 3x1 column vectors for the frenet frame and it's derivative and so I figured if I wanted to keep it in terms of T,N and B I should do it that way. You're saying that both F' and A should be 3x3 matrices? Should I just write out a 3x3 matrix using say the coordinate components of T,N and B as elements and proceed that way?

Comment: Think of it diagrammatically the way I did it. Remember that multiplying a matrix by a vector takes *linear combinations of the columns* with coefficients the entries of that vector.